# How to update database records within a user input range?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-update, ms-access-2010

I am trying to update database records over a range in Access using SQL and C#. Using an `UPDATE` query keeps giving me an error

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression

All of the query criteria is from user input. I have tried a number of sources to find an answer but I believe my SQL statement is correct. Below is the method that is performing the task that I need.

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        int teamYear = Convert.ToInt32(this.textBoxBegYear.Text);
        int endYear = Convert.ToInt32(this.textBoxEndYear.Text);
        string teamName = this.textBoxTeamName.Text;
        string league = this.textBoxLeague.Text;
        string conference = this.textBoxConf.Text;
        string division = this.textBoxDivision.Text;

        try
        {
            dbConn = new OleDbConnection();
            dbConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" 
               + ch + openFileDialog1.FileName + ch;
            dbConn.Open();

            sql = "UPDATE " + this.comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() 
               + " SET LeagueName = @leagueName, ConferenceName = @conferenceName, 
               DivisionName = @divisionName WHERE TeamName = " + this.textBoxTeamName.Text 
               + " AND TeamYear BETWEEN " + this.textBoxBegYear.Text 
               + " AND " + this.textBoxEndYear.Text;

            dbCmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, dbConn);

            for (int i = teamYear; i <= endYear; i++)
            {
                dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@leagueName", league);
                dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@conferenceName", conference);
                dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@divisionName", division);
                dbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            dbCmd.Connection.Close();
            dbConn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + err.Message.ToString());
        }
}
```

The exception comes from the second half of the SQL statement after the `WHERE` clause asking for a missing operator.

Can anyone happen to see what I may be missing? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This code is a security nightmare - do not take user input and directly form sql statements from it.  You are vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: You've got SQL injection issues. And I think you're missing some '' around this.textBoxTeamName.Text

Comment: Oh poor little bobby tables! https://xkcd.com/327/  Everyone always forgets about you :(

Comment: I will upvote Bobby Tables references, every time.

Comment: @womp, Kritner, I added the bobby-Tables reference too :)

Comment: @womp about to update all of my answers on all questions with little bobby tables references. please view my profile to more easily find answers to upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you replace the code in the "try" block to this:

```
        dbConn = new OleDbConnection();
        dbConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" 
           + ch + openFileDialog1.FileName + ch;
        dbConn.Open();

        sql = "UPDATE " + this.comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() 
           + " SET LeagueName = @leagueName, ConferenceName = @conferenceName, 
           DivisionName = @divisionName WHERE TeamName = @teamName AND TeamYear BETWEEN @begYear AND @endYear";

        dbCmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, dbConn);

        for (int i = teamYear; i <= endYear; i++)
        {
            dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@leagueName", league);
            dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@conferenceName", conference);
            dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@divisionName", division);
            dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@teamName", this.textBoxTeamName.Text);
            dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@begYear", int.Parse(this.textBoxBegYear.Text));
            dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endYear", int.Parse(this.textBoxBegYear.Text));
            dbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        dbCmd.Connection.Close();
        dbConn.Close();
```

Therefore, you have better idea what the SQL query looks like, and you parameterize users' input to improve security (prevent any sql injection).

To troubleshoot your issue, you may need to debug into this piece of code and see what's the SQL query is, and try to execute it from your SQL client tool (such as Sql management studio), you will have better idea what goes wrong.

Hope this helps.
Henry Liang

Answer (score 1):

You might be missing single quotes `'`...

```
TeamName = '" + this.textBoxTeamName.Text + "'
```

Also, I'm assuming this is just a project you're playing around with and nothing that will be available online? Reason I ask is that the SQL query is [`vulnerable to SQL injection attacks`](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Yes this is something I will be messing around with for personal use, definitely NOT online.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the text from the user input with single quotes.

```
WHERE TeamName = '" + this.textBoxTeamName.Text 
               + "' AND TeamYear BETWEEN " + this.textBoxBegYear.Text 
               + " AND " + this.textBoxEndYear.Text;
```

(Notice the single quotes).

Please do not use the code you posted.  Please read up on SQL Injection attacks and why your code is very unsafe and replace it with some properly cleaned input handling.

Comment: This is a personal project i am just trying to create a means where I do not have to do a lot of typing.